# Sum of numbers on 36 dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If 36 dice are rolled, find approximately the probability that the sum of the numbers appeared on them is between 110 and 130.

How do you approach such a problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Normal approximation. Let $X_i$ be the number on the $i$-th die. Let $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_{36}$. This sum has a roughly normal distribution. You can find the mean and variance of the normal once you know the mean and variance of $X_i$.

Comment: How can you just assume that it is approximately normal distribution?

Comment: It is a sum of a not too small number of independent identically distributed random variables whose distribution is not too wild.

Answer (score 2):

Outline: Use the normal approximation. For $i=1$ to $36$, let random variable $X_i$ be the number obtained on the $i$-th die.

Let $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_{36}$. We want $\Pr(110\le Y\le 130)$. Find the mean and the variance of the $X_i$. For the mean and variance of $Y$, multiply by $36$. Let the mean and variance of $Y$ be $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ respectively.

A reasonable approximation to our probability is the probability that a normal with  mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ lands between $110$ and $130$.

A continuity correction should lead to a better approximation. So it may be better to compute the probability that the normal $W$ is between $109.5$ and $130.5$.

Comment: @ AndreNicholas for the variance do we use central limit theorem?

Comment: You meant we want $Pr(110 \leq Y \leq 130)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks, yes, it is $Y$

Comment: @user34304: The variance of $Y$ is $36$ times the variance of $X_i$. I imagine you founf that the mean $E(X_i)$ of $X_i$ is $7/2$. For the variance of $X_i$, we find $E(X_i^2)-(E(X_i))^2$. For $E(X_i^2)$, we find $\frac{1}{6}(1^2+2^2+\cdots +6^2)$. So the variance of $X_i$ is $(91/6)-(7/2)^2$.  I think this is $35/12$.